# Solr - undefined method `results' for Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

I'm working on a project on Ruby on rails and wanted to added a search feature. I installed the solr gem following the steps from this site: 
http://es.asciicasts.com/episodes/278-busquedas-con-sunspot

right now, this is how my controller looks like:

```
class DealsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    # @deals = Deal.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @search = Deal.search do  
      fulltext params[:search]  
    end  
    @deals = @search.results
  end

  private
  def deal_params    
    params.require(:deal).permit(:title)
  end
end
```

this is my model:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base    
  searchable do  
    text :title, :info1, :page 
  end 
end
```

and this is my view:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row upper_container'>
    <div class='search_container'>
        <%= form_tag deals_path, :method => :get, :class => 'navbar-form navbar-left' do %>  
        <div class='form-group'>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <%= submit_tag 'Search', :name => nil %>
      <% end %> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <% @deals.each_with_index do |d, i| %>
    <% if i % 3 == 0 %>
      <div class='row middle_container'>
    <% end %>  
      <div class='col-md-4'>
        <div class='deal_container'>
          <%= d.title %>
          <img src='<%= d.photo %>'>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% if (i % 3 == 2) || (i == (@deals.length - 1))  %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <div class='text-center'>
    <%= will_paginate @deals %>
  </div>
</div>
```

But i get the following error:

undefined method `results' for Ransack::Search>:Ransack::Search

on this line: `@deals = @search.results`

Any help? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jude, change your

```
@deals = @search.results
```

to

```
@deals = @search.result
```

Comment: `result` and `results` are two different methods, and are *not interchangeable*. Please see the project source for details, and use the `solr_search` solution I have recommended below.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance using the [sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) gem?

> If you are using Active Admin and the Sunspot gem for Rails, beware:
>   they conflict on the search method leading to some very confusing
>   results.
>
> Active Admin has a dependency on meta_search which provides a
>   .search() method on Active Record classes. Sunspot attempts to provide
>   the same method, aliased from solr_search, but only if the method does
>   not already exist.
>
> **In short, searching can be done using solr_search() rather than**
>   **search():**

```
@search = Profile.solr_search do
  keywords params[:q]
  paginate page: params[:page], per_page: page_size
end

@results = @search.results
```

http://mrdanadams.com/2012/beware-using-active_admin-and-sunspot-rails-gems-together/